# Eevee render create contour like appearance

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I am still new to Blender and I made this render using Eevee. As you can see the render quality is pretty bad and there are contour like appearance in some places. Also it looks like everything is covered by a fine mist or fog. I used sampling 500 but still the same issue. Any help?[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about color banding?  Some color banding is unavoidable at low brightnesses (function of the limits of our display tech, and yes, how bad it is depends on each viewer's monitor and how it is set up physically), but you can play with dither in properties/output/post processing.  The "fog" is probably bloom, which you can disable in properties/render; disabling this will probably also fix any apparent banding problems.  Increasing sample count will not help.

Comment: Thank you Nathan I didn't know the correct terminology. Thank you for the help.